# Diagnose NoClassDefFoundError during Spring Boot when class is available to ClassLoader

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, spring-boot

I have a Java/Maven project (POM-based) which **builds and launches fine** when using `java -jar` on the uber JAR produced by my Maven build on the command line, using the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`:

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>com.company.Application</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>repackage</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

The JAR is created (~100MB), and **launches as expected.**

However, I'm unable to launch this same application in Eclipse using the right-click -> Run As -> Java Application configuration on the main class I've defined in my POM. It's a Maven project, and M2E is up-to-date/refreshed, etc.

The error is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
```

So clearly some dependency issues with the logging frameworks. **However:** My first head-scratcher was, *why does this work in Maven using the CLI, and fail in Eclipse using M2E?*

So I went and looked at the classpaths, and they seem identical. (Looking at the Maven Dependencies list in Eclipse, and the BOOT-INF directory contained in my uber JAR.) The interesting bits are:

```
slf4j-api        1.7.25
log4j-over-slf4j 1.7.25
logback-core     1.2.3
logback-classic  1.2.3
commons-logging  1.1.3
```

**So, I debugged.** I placed a breakpoint on `NoClassDefFoundError`, and captured this. Note that the debugger is paused on the thrown exception, and the **watch expression** in the upper-right is `getClass().getClassLoader().classes`, which is a `Vector`.

How is it possible that we're throwing on `LoggerFactory`, even though this very class is present in the current `ClassLoader`? Where should I look next?

[image]

**Edit:** Since it's causing some confusion, the class in which Eclipse has caught this error (`Category.java`) is not one of my classes. It's inside a dependency (see Eclipse titlebar) and as a result cannot be modified.

Comment: `Could not initialize class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory` - something bad happened in static initializer.Wrap call to `LoggerFactory.getLogger()` in try/catch and use e.getCause().printStackTrace() or `e.getCause()` to find out what.

Comment: But the call itself (`LoggerFactory.getLogger()`) is what's throwing the `NoClassDefFoundError`. Won't wrapping it in a try/catch (which I can't really do anyway since `Category.java` is inside the `log4j-over-slf4j` dependency) just result in me catching a `NoClassDefFoundError`? I've inspected this error and there is no deeper root/cause.